# VirtualBox with Ubuntu Server guest can't ping outside

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, nat

Here's my situation:

- an Ubuntu 12.04 Host running VirtualBox;
- two guest VMs running Ubuntu Server 12.04
- home network, so my Host pc has a wireless connection to the router of my ISP.

My problem is in one of the virtual machines: it has 3 NICs, one in NAT mode and the others in Host Only mode. My purpose is to use eth0 (NAT) for Internet access and eth1, eth2 (Host Only) for management of internal virtual network (eth1 uses a VBoxNet with this IP 192.168.69.254).

Whenever I try to `$ping 8.8.8.8` I get `Destination Host Unreachable`.

While if I `$ping 192.168.69.10`, that is the IP of the other VM, it works.

I can't also ping my Host nor my router

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is:
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.69.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth2
iface ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
down ip link set $IFASE promisc off
down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

`$route -n` returns:

```
Destination   Gateway     Genmask        Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0       10.0.2.2    0.0.0.0        UG    100    0   0   eth0
10.0.2.0       0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U       0    0   0   eth0 
192.168.69.0   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U       0    0   0   eth1
192.168.100.0  0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U       0    0   0   virbr0
```

Forgetting for now what eth2 needs to do and its setup, why I can't go outside the Host box?

What can I do to help you helping me? :-)

---

-Edit-

On my Host:
`$ ifconfig -a`

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 00:26:9e:d5:1a:bb  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:0 (0.0 B)

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:17:fe:17:31:b3  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.1.186  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::c617:feff:fe17:31b3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1774067 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3371346
      TX packets:1486276 errors:266 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:1642836807 (1.6 GB)  Byte TX:170395284 (170.3 MB)
      Interrupt:16 

lo    Link encap:Loopback locale  
      indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
      indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:9119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0 
      Byte RX:1089979 (1.0 MB)  Byte TX:1089979 (1.0 MB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.69.254  Bcast:192.168.69.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:345450 (345.4 KB)

vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 0a:00:27:00:00:01  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.57.1  Bcast:192.168.57.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2082 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:331256 (331.2 KB)
```

Comment: can you show the output of ifconfig -a on the host?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using NAT for eth0 instead of bridged?

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg Can you bridge over wlan0? His host is connected to his router via wifi

Comment: @Danidan Could you just make an experiment? Comment out all lines referring to eth1 and eth2 in /etc/network/interfaces on your guest, and restart the VM. Can you connect to the internet right now?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: I don't see why not, but I've never tried.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I edited the question with `ifconfig -a` as you requested. Also I commented the lines you said in my guest VM and nothing changed...

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg read David Schwartz's reply at the bottom of this page http://superuser.com/questions/597834/bridging-wifi-to-ethernet-on-ubuntu-not-working

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I tried also bridged but with no luck. Furthermore I added port forwarding on port 80 in NAT mode...

Comment: @Danidan Back in NAT mode, try running `ifconfig` inside the guest to find out if `eth0` got a valid IP address. Then, from the guest, try to ping the host (which should be 10.0.2.2, based on your routing table). Does the host system respond to ping?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing my virtualbox network adapter from "NAT" to "bridge adapter".

You can use NAT for port forwardind. So you can, for example, configure your forwarding table to forward request from port 8080 to your virtual server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will resolve your issue or not, as perhaps it is not exactly the same issue as mine, since you are using NAT, but I think it is worth a try.

I was having a similar issue where I could not ping my host or the router or any other box from the Ubuntu VM.  I had set up a bridged WiFi adapter via Machine -> Settings -> Network options in VBox.

But then I noticed that there were actually two Wifi adapters listed:

```
Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter 

Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
```

I had selected the Microsoft one first, and then when I switched to the Realtek one and restarted the VM, the issue was resolved for me.